# Count the maximum date between consecutive dates and corresponding value using 3 columns

Tags: r, datetime

I have this data:

```
 df<-airquality[1:30,]
 df$duration<- rep(c(1,NA,0,2,0,0,3,0,NA,1),3)
 df$Year<- rep(1900,30)
 df$Dates <-as.Date(ISOdate(df$Year,df$Month, df$Day))
```

I need 2 new column df$MaxWind (contain max value of Wind according to duration) and df$MaxDates(contain corresponding date of max wind) like this:

```
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day duration Year      Dates  MaxWind MaxDates
     41     190  7.4   67     5   1        1 1900 1900-05-01     7.4  1900-05-01  
     36     118  8.0   72     5   2       NA 1900 1900-05-02      NA          NA
     12     149 12.6   74     5   3        0 1900 1900-05-03      NA          NA
     18     313 11.5   62     5   4        2 1900 1900-05-04     14.3 1900-05-05
     NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5        0 1900 1900-05-05      NA          NA
     28      NA 14.9   66     5   6        0 1900 1900-05-06      NA          NA 
     23     299  8.6   65     5   7        3 1900 1900-05-07     20.1 1900-05-09
     19      99 13.8   59     5   8        0 1900 1900-05-08      NA          NA
      8      19 20.1   61     5   9       NA 1900 1900-05-09      NA          NA
```

We can repeat the MaxWind and the Maxdates for the duration (NA or O) or replace it by NA as I do here.

I try with `pmax` command but I dont know how to affect the max value of wind.

```
library(plyr) 
df<-ddply(df, "Wind", transform,MaxDates= pmax(match(Dates,Dates+ duration -1))
```

I get error :

> Error in if (empty(.data)) return(.data) : 
>   valeur manquante là où TRUE / FALSE est requis

Comment: Not clear as to how you calculate the maximums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
library(plyr)

maxWindDate <- function(row) {
  in.range <- row$Dates <= df$Dates & df$Dates - row$duration < row$Dates
  winds <- df$Wind[in.range]
  dates <- df$Dates[in.range]
  if (length(winds) == 0) {
    data.frame(maxWind=NA, maxDate=NA)
  } else {
    maxWind <- max(winds)
    maxDate <- dates[which(winds == maxWind)[1]]
    data.frame(maxWind=maxWind, maxDate=maxDate)
  }
}

df <- adply(df, 1, maxWindDate)
```

Comment: This gives me exactly what I want. Thank you very much @fjarino